# str_replace inside while statement

Tags: php, while-loop, str-replace

Why the str_replace I have inside a while loop does not act as expected?

My code:

```
    $comments=$_POST['comments'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cust LEFT JOIN contact AS contact ON cust.cid=contact.contact_id WHERE cid='$aDoor[$i]'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $petname=$row['petname'];
      echo "Petname ".$petname."<br/>";
      $comments=str_replace("+petname","$petname",$comments);
      echo $comments."<br/>";
}
```

The strangest thing happens when I execture this code.
The line: 
`echo "Petname ".$petname."<br/>";` 
works as expected, and echos the correct petname in the database for the cid.
BUT
The line:

```
$comments=str_replace("+petname","$petname",$comments);
echo $comments."<br/>";
```

Will always show the name of the FIRST pet pulled. How can this be when Im adding the $petname that is correct to the comments variable?

P.S. The reason im doing the str_replace is so the person who will use this can type in +pet when he sends an email to his clients, and when it arrives to the client, it will have the correct pet name.

Comment: Was `$comments` defined before, because it seems to me that it isn't in `str_replace("+petname","$petname",$comments);`.

Comment: I need it to make the line stand out, I could use some other char and try I guess.

Comment: Where is $comments defined?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt include where that is at the top of the page. $comments is a get request from the form that send the info to this php page.

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `$comments` is being redefined after you loop it the first time, so say if `$comments` at the beginning was `+petname`, after you replace it, `$comments` will hold the value of the petname in the row, then it loops again with the value of `$comments` being the pet name, to solve this, simply change the name of the variables

```
$comments=$_POST['comments'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cust LEFT JOIN contact AS contact ON    cust.cid=contact.contact_id WHERE cid='$aDoor[$i]'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $petname=$row['petname'];
    echo "Petname ".$petname."<br/>";
    $comment_replaced=str_replace("+petname","$petname",$comments);
    echo $comment_replaced."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: 100% correct. Wow I cant believe I missed that. Thank you very much for you quick response!

Comment: @user1789437 No problem, choosing my question as the correct answer would be helpful to me if this indeed was the correct answer.

Comment: I just did! If I want to do the same for 4 more variables, what would be the best method for this? 4 more str_replace statements? Or can you replace 5 things in once statement? I realize this is a new question but if you can help id be in your debt!

Comment: @user1789437 You mean you want to replace (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`) all with `x`?

Comment: This works: $comments_replaced=str_replace("+petname","$petname",$comments);
  $comments_replaced=str_replace("+nextvisit","$emailnextvisit",$comments_replaced);
  $comments_replaced=str_replace("+lastvisit","$emaillastvisit",$comments_replaced);
  $comments_replaced=str_replace("+nextservice","$next_service",$comments_replaced);  Why would the last 3 allow for the same var but not the first?